# pip3 outputs newlines instead of installing

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pip

When I try to install literaly any module, this happens:

```
c:\>pip3 --no-cache install requests
Collecting requests
Downloading requests-2.13.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (584kB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 593kB 730kB/s
Installing collected packages: requests
```

Then a bunch of newlines...

```
c:\>
```

This never happened to me before.

I think this might be important: when I first tried to install requests today, avast wanted to scan pip3, because it thought that it might be a threat (silly avast!). I told it to stop.

Comment: What is your default Python installation, 2 or 3?

Comment: Python 3.6 and it is the only one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be something wrong with how `pip3` was installed or configured. Using `pip` will point to the default Python installation's pip version. Try:

```
pip install requests
```

If that does not work, try

```
python -m pip install requests
```

**EDIT**: As David mentioned in the comments, disabling the antivirus and reinstalling Python also fixes the problem.

Comment: Same thing for both. Also, I disabled avast's cyber capture.

Comment: Can you restart and try again?

Comment: Still same thing. I guess now I should repair, or reinstall python?

Comment: At this point, I personally am not sure how to resolve the issue. Reinstalling might work.

Comment: It did. Disabling CyberCapture in Avast also helped.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for letting us know!